# Delete files that don't match a particular string format

Tags: linux, bash, macos, find

I have a set of files that are named similarly:

```
TEXT_TEXT_YYYYMMDD
```

Example file name:

```
My_House_20170426
```

I'm trying to delete all files that don't match this format. Every file should have a string of text followed by an underscore, followed by another string of text and another underscore, then a date stamp of YYYYMMDD.

Can someone provide some advice on how to build a `find` or a `remove` statement that will delete files that don't match this format?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: try playing with `echo My_House_20170426 | grep -E 'pattern'` until it matches correctly. Then use the `-q` option of grep and use it like this: `if echo $filename | grep -qE pattern ; then ...`

Comment: Actually see if you can use `find path -not -regex pattern -delete`. Test first without `-delete`.

Comment: wrt `a date stamp of YYYYMMDD` - what if a file is named `text_text_86753090` or some other combination of 8-digits that isn't a valid date? Remove it or keep it?

Comment: As long as there are eight digits I can be assured the data is correctly formatted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `find`, add `-delete` to the end once you're sure it works.

```
# gnu find
find . -regextype posix-egrep -type f -not -iregex '.*/[a-z]+_[a-z]+_[0-9]{8}'

# OSX find
find -E . -type f -not -iregex '.*/[a-z]+_[a-z]+_[0-9]{8}'
```

Intentionally only matching alphabetical characters for TEXT. Add `0-9` to each TEXT area like this `[a-z0-9]` if you need numbers.

Comment: There might be a couple of things to consider here, otherwise it's a decent solution. I would probably use `[a-z0-9]` at least in case a filename has numbers in it, otherwise files like `file1_name_20170425` are gone too. The other thing I might mention is that if there's a directory `some_directory_123` it won't be removed if it has a file that isn't supposed to removed within it — that may be fine, just pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -v '(pattern)'
```

will filter out lines that match a pattern, leaving those that don't match. You might try piping in the output of `ls`. And if you're particularly brave, you could pipe the output to something like `xargs rm`. But deleting is kinda scary, so maybe save the output to a file first, look at it, then delete the files listed.

Comment: +1 for recommending not to use `xargs rm` until you are comfortable finding the correct files first. Last thing you want is to come back asking if there is anyway to recover files accidentally deleted